# Java RunTime Error UVA 11877 Coca Cola

Tags: java

I'm working on [UVA 11877 Coca Cola](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/118/11877.html), here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
  private static Scanner sc;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int j;
    Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cs = st.nextInt();
    int a = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    while (a < cs) {
      int i = st.nextInt();
      j = freeBottle(i);
      a++;
      free = 0;
      System.out.println(j);
    }
  }

  static int free;

  static int freeBottle(int i) {
    int temp = 0;
    while (i >= 3) {
      temp++;
      i = i - 3;
    }
    free = free + temp;
    int p = temp + i;
    if (p > 2) {
      freeBottle((temp + i));
    }
    if (p == 2) {
      free++;
    }
    return free;
  }
}
```

when I submit it on UVA it always returns a `RuntimeError`, it also fails on ideone.com.  But I don't get any errors in Eclipse.  What is the problem?

I see this problem in submissions for other problems too.

Comment: 'Runtime Error' is a bit vague.  What error, specifically, are you getting when you submit your code?

Comment: Could those environments not have a System.in stream?

Comment: @azurefrog Unfortunately that is the nature of the UVA problem set - if it gets a `RuntimeError` while running, that's all it tells you.

Comment: Well to use this program with ideone.com you need to define some input in STDIN (http://ideone.com/rCb4Ry), the run-time error seems to be thrown as soon as your code tried to fetch the `nextInt()` when there is not more to process.  But the output doesn't match what the linked question is expecting so it looks like you have more work to do :)

Comment: free is a static variable, could be the source of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with some basic sanity checks.  When I run your code against the sample input, I get the wrong answer:

```
// Your code
Scanner st = new Scanner("3\n10\n81\n0");
// Your code
```

> ```
> 5
> 40
> 0
> ```

Do you see the right answer (`1`, `5`, `40`) when you run your code in Eclipse?  I suspect not - at least not with the code you posted.

By the looks of it, you are expecting the first line to be the number of results that follow, which isn't correct.  The problem says the input consists of:

> at most 10 test cases, each containing a single line with an integer `n` (`1 <= n <= 100`). The input terminates with `n = 0`, which should not be processed.

So as a first pass, I would suggest double checking that you are reading the input correctly, and seeing the expected output for the sample input.  From there, experiment with other inputs that fit the above description, such as a single `1` (followed by a `0`) and ten `100`s.

To get you started, here's a loop that will correctly read the inputs (note the use of [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which you should be using):

```
try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  while(in.hasNextInt()) {
    int bottles = in.nextInt();
    if(bottles == 0) {
      break;
    }
    // process bottles
  }
}
```